# Changing a Active Record DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app I created with based on a DB with a table named "countries", which stored a list of all the countries in the world. Now I have found out that the actual DB I will be using uses a table named "ctry" instead (stupid I know). What I am trying to figure out is if there is any way I can point active record to this new table without having to swap out every single instance in "countries" from the controller names, file names, etc.

I'm not at all sure if this could possibly be done with routes or how someone might do it.

This is the active record model as it exists now:

```
class countries < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "ctry"
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002286

Comment: Thank you. You saved my sanity big time. I kept searching through the ROR api with no luck. This definitely helps. Thanks again

Comment: If the database is only going to be used by your rails app going forward, you could also rename the table in MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html

Comment: Further: You could also rename the table in a migration with "rename_table('ctry', 'countries')".

Comment: Thank you askegg, that was very helpful actually